# MAUI Blazor scrollable <div>

Tags: html, scroll, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I have a Table with headers and a body. I want the headers to stay at the top of the page but make the table body scrollable.
I am using bootstrap with Blazor and tried:

```
<tbody class="overflow-auto">
```

and

```
<tbody style="overflow:auto">
```

I have also tried putting my entire blazor page in:

```
<div class="overflow-hidden">
```

It should make it so that the scrollbar doesn't appear at all. But when the MAUI screen is downsized to the point where the html doesn't fit the window. It keeps putting the scrollbar there.

I think the scrolling is MAUI specific and doesn't work like a traditional browser handles it.

Maybe i can disable scrolling in the MAUI components but there is already a lot of logic between items above the table body and the table body itself so i rather not split these up in to multiple blazor components.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a class like this for the element

```
<tbody class="classname">
```

Then in your css file

```
.classname::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    display: none;
}
```

This is what worked for me.